# display datetime as yyyy/mm/dd in asp mvc/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I use the following code to convert an datetimestring to datetime.

```
string str1 = "1392/02/10 22:30:15";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(str1, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have a problem that when it convert to datetime I need to display 
`1392/02/10 22:30:15` I mean as a `yyyy/mm/dd` but it display `02/10/1392  22:30:15` as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: Can you show your code where you display the `DateTime`, rather than where you parse it?

Comment: The parser should be working fine. Perhaps the string formatting was gone wrong treating parsed `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format specifier you pass to `ParseExact` tells C# how to convert a string into a DateTime, but you want to convert DateTime to a string.

You can pass a [custom format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to the `DateTime.ToString()` method.

```
string display = d.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert date to string before displaying.

```
string strDate = d.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```